Edit macro before compiling - gcc
using gcc or a similar compiler, is it possible to increment a macro in the code before compiling?
For example, if in the header.h file I have something like:
#define EXAMPLE 5

I would like that before compiling, this become:
#define EXAMPLE 6

Is there a way to do this?

There is no direct way to do this, however you could:

Use some kind of build script: eg a bash script that modifies the header file or the definition of the macro before the compilation process
Pass the definition from the compiler command line: You can define macros using GCC's -D option. This allows you to overwrite the value specified in the source code, this also precedes the code definition. For example:
 gcc -D EXAMPLE=6 file.c 


You can also conditionally choose the value with:
#if !defined(EXAMPLE)
#define EXAMPLE 5
#endif




2&3 together will solve most cases where you might want this, without having to do build-time source changes

I think that in my case, the solution must derive from 1. 2&3 In my case they are not applicable because I have to enter the numbers manually, instead I would like them to be automatically incremented at the time of build.

Perfect, shall we mark it closed?

Check to see what exactly you wanted to achieve by doing above. If its basically you need to have a unique value based on each compilation, then use a built-in macro for this:
TIMESTAMP link
Even better you could new C++ constexp: link to get unique number you want for each compile instance, however it will require newer version of C++
Alternatively, you can surely use other techniques like using compiler flags or external scripts but only to add unneeded complexity only.
